# file_gets_content on the same server, i dont want to get the php code

Tags: php

I know that `file_gets_content` on a php file hosted on the same server return the text and the PHP code, but I dont want to have the PHP code how to do that ?

Ex :

```
<?php function getOneExp(){
$fp=file_get_contents("exp.txt");
$exp=  (explode(',',$fp));
shuffle($exp);
return str_replace(" ","-",utf8_decode(trim(ucfirst(strtolower($exp[0])))));
}
?>

SOME TEXT <? echo getOneExp() ?> ANOTHER TEXT
```

If I make a file gets content on this file I get the php too, because its on the same server, but I dont want to have the PHP,

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps use `include`?

Comment: Mmmh complicated in my scope.. Not another possibilities ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `include` is a much better solution but if you don't like it, here's an alternative for you.

You can use either `cURL` or `file_get_contents(`) with the actual web url. For example, if your domain name is **example.com** and the file name is **test.php**, then you can use this inside another php file -

```
<?php
$output = file_get_contents("http://example.com/test.php");
```